# how to get people picker field value and store it in a variable

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, people-picker

i have a small requirement where in, i have a column  "Employee Name" as a people picker field, now i just want to retrieve the employee name value in a variable after the user has entered his name in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract Display Name from people picker element by following statement.

```
var employeeName = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict["EmployeeName_TopSpan"].GetAllUserInfo()[0].DisplayText
```

Please note: "EmployeeName" here in "EmployeeName_TopSpan" is the people picker div element id

and

assuming that people picker will have only entry therefore we have taken zeroth index result from `GetAllUserInfo` method.

Comment: Hi yayati , 
in regard to your answer, how do i find out the div element id, i have inspected the element and the id i get is "id1b_fb02312c-4006-49bf-be76-f3fc26f5f5bf_$ClientPeoplePicker". Also, how do i write this down, will this work in PreSaveAction function?

Comment: do i need to reference SPservices file for this code too?

Comment: No need to reference SPService file. Try replacing `EmployeeName_TopSpan` with `id1b_fb02312c-4006-49bf-be76-f3fc26f5f5bf_$ClientPeoplePicker` in the above script.

Comment: i did that too but it did not work

Comment: Are you using default NewItem form or custom form?

Comment: default new item form, also it is throwing a error in console saying , "cannot read property 'GetAllUserInfo'" of undefined

Comment: it is working thank you so much